# how to fix MethodNotAllowedHttpException in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i'm creating function delete in laravel and here is my Controller

```
public function removePetitions($id)
{
    $rm = Petitions::find($id);
    $rm->delete();
    return ['status' => true];
}
```

and here is my route

```
Route::post('/delete/petition/{id}','Admin\PetitionController@removePetitions')->name('admin.delete');
```

when i click button delete in view it show MethodNotAllowedHttpException. anyone solve that??? thank u

Comment: In way you are using id I think you have get call so try with Route::get...

Comment: i using ajax to submit action, and method in ajax i'm using POST

Comment: In case you are using ajax, did you send CSRF token in call?

Comment: in view i used <a href="{{ route('admin.delete',$petition->id)}}" class="pull-right btn-del-petition" data-id="{{$petition->id}}">Del</a> and it's response right url i defined in route but it's still not working

Comment: You are deleting record using ajax call ? @NguyễnMinhHuy

Comment: yeahhh, i want to del record

Comment: Ok but i am asking you are deleting using ajax call?

Comment: yeahhhhh @kunal

Comment: I'm not sure, because I can't see your javascript code, but how you are doing ajax call in case in anchor you are define real URL? At least I think you'll making double call - one by pressing anchor and eventually another one if you react on event by javascript code. This answer is for get call made by pressing anchor. But this is onli a think, I'm not using behavior like yours and not sure.

Comment: Ok give me few minutes i provide you full code with detailed description

Comment: OK, you are really using post method and there no double call but I don't see to use CSRF header. Did you include this route into CSRF exceptions?

Comment: i think if missing CSRF it will show CSRF token miss match ????

Comment: I'm not sure, but mismatch will be if you are sending a old token but now you don't send any token. But I really can't understand why you are using post method in case the parameter is in url.

Comment: okay thank @KanchoIliev :) perhaps i should check it again

Comment: seems like m late to party but from your code looks like you have two routes with wild card support and you are not probably hitting the route intended and hitting the wrong route.. hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your problem You are looking for this kin of stuff

```
Your anchor tag here look like this:-
<a href="javascript:;" class="pull-right btn-del-petition" data-id="{{$petition->id}}">Del</a>
And route looklike this :-
Route::post('/delete/petition','Admin\PetitionController@removePetitions');
```

And now ajax code :-

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" /> // add in head tag
$.ajaxSetup({
headers:{
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
}); 
$(document).on('click','.btn-del-petition',function(){
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'delete/petition',
    data: {id :id},
    success:function(resp){
        alert(resp);
        //Delete that deleted row with jquery
    },
    error:function(){
        alert('Error');
    }
})
})
```

Now your function :-

```
public function removePetitions(Request $request)
{
if($request->ajax()){
    $data = $request->all();
    $rm = Petitions::find($data['id']);
    $rm->delete();
    return ['status' => true];
}
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: To work this, won't it needed to change the route from '/delete/petition/{id}' to '/delete/petition'

Comment: see my route now